# Value not obtainable in child component when downpassing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to downpass the isOpen prop to the Snackbar component, but for some reason when I console.log this.props in either the componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate all I see is this.props.message. If anyone could help me out that would be greatly appreciated, seeing as how this problem costs me a lot of time yet it seems so simple. Thanks in advance!

### Parent component

```
{this.state.message.message ? <SnackBar message={this.state.message.message} isOpen={true}/> : null}
```

### Snackbar component

```
class SnackBar extends Component {
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
   open: false,
  };
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps,nextProps) {
  console.log(this.props);
  console.log(prevProps, nextProps);

}
```

Comment: Just to make sure - can you make it `isopen` instead of `isOpen`?

Comment: The code you have shared is looking fine. Try to print your props inside constructor itself. However, if it doesn't solve your issue try passing the value for isOpen as you did with message. i.e. isOpen={this.state.openVal} where openVal is true.

Comment: though I don't think it's camelCase issue. It should show up in componentDidMount

Comment: @Upasana Here thanks for the suggestion I tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't work.... do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @ErhunYilman With the above shared code everything seems fine. It would be helpful if you can share more code here? A quick question, Are you using material-ui component Snackbar or a simple react one?

Comment: @Upasana I use material ui 1.0. I did what you suggested I added openVal: true in the constructor in the parent component: `constructor(props) { super(props); this.state = { message: { type: null, message: null }, small: false, itemToDelete: null, allChecked: false, openVal: true };` And I passed it like this to the Snackbar component: `{this.state.message.message ? <SnackBar message={this.state.message.message} isopen={this.state.openVal}/> : null}` But unfortunately I get nothing when I console.log it in the snackbar component

Comment: If you are using material ui's then why are you not using it's 'Snackbar' component directly rather making snackbar react component ? Could you share your code example on codepen or something like that?  So that I can look at it my end.

Answer (score 0):

From React docs for `componentDidUpdate`:

`This method is not called for the initial render.`

And `componentDidMount` doesn't get props as arguments, you have to use `this.props`.

```
class SnackBar extends Component {
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
   open: false,
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.props)
}
```

Comment: Nothing about the props changes between the contructor and `componentDidMount`, so why would it?

Comment: Ah wait, small mistake, check my edit. Still, just log it in the constructor.